# php ckeditor can't set php data

Tags: php, ckeditor

```
<textarea cols="80"  id="editor1"    name="content" rows="10" >    
</textarea>     
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
```

That is working properly and I am getting the edit textbox, but now I need to get data from the database.
For that I am doing:

```
<textarea cols="80"  id="editor1" value="<?php echo $rows['content']; ?>"   name="content" rows="10" >  

</textarea>         
<script>
      CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
```

But it does not show me my data.

I have tried data I am getting in simple textarea but not in CKEDITOR.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: <textarea cols="80"  id="editor1" name="content" rows="10" >

    <?php echo $rows['content']; ?>

</textarea>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<textarea cols="80"  id="editor1" name="content" rows="10" >

    <?php echo $rows['content']; ?>

</textarea>
```

Try this. Hope this help. Thank You :-)

Answer (score 1):

Textarea value should be stored inside textarea, not in value attribute:

```
<textarea> <?= $value ?> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

`textarea` Don't have `value` attribute.
Use this code:

```
<textarea cols="80"  id="editor1" name="content" rows="10" >

    <?php echo $rows['content']; ?>

</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted to replace the entire editor content, in which case you'd want to use [setData()](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData).

or you can also use

Use [insertHtml()](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#insertHtml) or [insertText()](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#insertText) method.

or with sample php code as html by text aread

```
<textarea cols="80"  id="editor1" name="content" rows="10" >

    <?php echo $rows['content']; ?>

</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

i experienced this and solved this. i needed jquery.

first:
    `<textarea id = "editContent"> </textarea>`
    `<script>`
   `CKEDITOR.replace('editContent');`
  `</script>`

`<?php
    $content = $row['content'];
?>`

```
`<div id = "myDiv"><?php echo $content?></div>
```

`<script>
    CKEDITOR.instances.editContent.setData($("#myDiv").html());
</script>`

Comment: wow i did not think it was so strict to post some html php javascript. hope it will help you out like it did to me.